# How to consume functionalities of a website that requires a Facebook authentication?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website that requires any user to be logged in using the Facebook auth system.

On the other hand I am making an iOS App that needs to consume functionalities of the website. I implemented the SSO system on the iOS system but I don't get how I'm supposed to call my webservices in a way that tells the backend that "it's ok, I'm authenticated on the iOS app".

Is there anything to do with the signed_request parameters on the iOS side? If yes, I didn't find anyway yet to get that parameter.

Do you have any clue to help me deal with my issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

The `signed_request` parameter is utilized to share information between Facebook and app in a number of different scenarios:

- A `signed_request` is passed to Apps on Facebook.com when they are loaded into the Facebook environment
- A `signed_request` is passed to any app that has registered an Deauthorized Callback in the Developer App whenever a given user removes the app using the App Dashboard
- A `signed_request` is passed to apps that use the Registration Plugin whenever a user successfully registers with their app

Does iOS use any of these?

** EDIT **

> Ok thanks, can you edit your answer and add the fact that I can't
>   access the signed_request parameter? – MartinMoizard

From Martin:  iOS cannot access the signed request parameter probably because iOS is not a webserver that is able to accept HTTP Post paramteres.

Comment: Actually this is part of my question: "I didn't find anyway yet to get that parameter" on the iOS part

Comment: There's three ways to get it, so you will need to implement one of those three ways.  I would assume its not because those three ways are all for HTTP POSTs to a webserver and iOS is not really a web server language or server, right?  So if iOS is not something that runs a website, then you probably have no access from iOS to the signed_request form post parameter that is passed to the iframes URL.

Comment: Ok thanks, can you edit your answer and add the fact that I can't access the signed_request parameter?

Comment: Done. So your answer is that the signed_request cannot be used in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with this same problem, and it seems that OAuth is actually an authorization protocol, not an authentication protocol.  See:
http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/01/problem-with-oauth-for-authentication.html
Seems like the signed request would solve this problem nicely.  Not sure why we cannot get them on iOS.  Best I can figure out is I need to pass my access_token from the iOS client to my server, and then it can ask graph.facebook.com what user it represents.